# Why can't I use foreach on my Class?

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to use my custom class with an iterator, but it can't iterate on the elements using `foreach`. How can I deal with it?

```
public class FCSOfOtherClass<Double> {
private int n;
private Double[] a;

public FCSOfOtherClass(int cap) {
    a = (Double[]) new Object[cap];
}

public void push(Double dou) {
    if (a.length == n) {
        this.resize(2 * a.length);
        a[n++] = dou;
    } else {
        a[n++] = dou;
    }
}

private void resize(int max) {
    Double[] newa = (Double[]) new Object[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newa[i] = a[i];
        a = newa;
    }
}

public Boolean isEmpty() {
    return n == 0;
}

public Double pop() {
    Double dou = a[--n];
    a[n] = null;
    if (n > 0 && n == a.length / 2) {
        resize(a.length / 2);
    }
    return dou;
}

public int size() {
    return n;
}

public Iterator<Double> iterator() {
    return new RAIterator();
}

private class RAIterator implements Iterator<Double> {
    private int i = n;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Double next() {
        return a[--i];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {

    }

    @Override
    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Double> action) {

    }
```

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FCSOfOtherClass<Integer> fcs = new FCSOfOtherClass<>(100);
    int i = 0;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        fcs.push(++i);
    }
    for (int j:fcs) {
        StdOut.print(j);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error telling me that `foreach` is not applicable to my type.

Comment: A class must implement the Iterable interface to be able to be used in a for-each block.

Comment: Unrelated, but do not name the generic type parameter `Double`. It is *very* confusing, seeing variables of type `Double`, which are not `java.lang.Double`, but could be anything, e.g. `Fruit`. [Naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201707061649005848894) for type variables is to generally use a single upper case letter, most commonly `T`. In your case, `E` for "element" would be another appropriate name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `FCSOfOtherClass` does not implement `java.lang.Iterable`. The "foreach" loop only works on arrays and instances of `Iterable`.

You can address this by making your class implement `Iterable`:

```
public class FCSOfOtherClass implements java.lang.Iterable<Double> {
    ...
}
```

This requires that you provide an implementation for the interface method `iterator()`. Your sample code shows that you already do:

```
public Iterator<Double> iterator() {
    return new RAIterator();
}
```

This is covered in the Java Language Specification, [section 14.14.2: The enhanced `for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: The funny thing is that he did everything *almost* right — he just forgot to actually declare that his class implemented the `Iterable` interface ;)